# How many characters will hold if we define varchar in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Here is may code

```
Create table dbo.EXA
(
     Name  VARCHAR,
     ID    INT
)
```

How many character will hold data type `VARCHAR` as I am not defining the size?

or defining

```
 NAME VARCHAR
```

it self wrong?

Comment: go with TEXT in place of VARCHAR if you are not sure about the size being hold by your field

Comment: @HardikBhalani: **DO NOT USE** `TEXT` anymore!! It's (a) deprecated, (b) hard to use, and (c) typically WAY TOO MUCH data. This is **horribly bad** advice!

Answer (score 2):

You will get **EXACTLY ONE CHARACTER** - which is typically not what you want. This is in the case where you define a SQL Server variable, a parameter on a stored procedure, or a table column.

If you don't specify any length in `VARCHAR` in the context of a conversion using `CONVERT` or `CAST`, then the default is 30 characters.

My recommendation would be to **ALWAYS** explicitly define a length - then it's clear (to you, to T-SQL, to a poor guy who needs to maintain your code in a year) what you wanted/needed

Answer (score 0):

I connected to SQL Server 2005, ran the above and checked the table after completion and it set it automatically to one character.

Answer (score 0):

varchar is equivalent to varchar(1)
I tried this code  check this out
[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3984c/1)